# Xcode Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, widget

I have this error when I try to run my app on a device from XCode 7.3.1. Whenever I build my application I keep getting this error:

> error: Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent app.
> Verify the embedded binary target's code sign settings match the parent app's.
>
> Embedded Binary Signing Certificate: - (Ad Hoc Code Signed)
> Parent App Signing Certificate: iPhone Distribution: XXXXXXX (XXXXXXXX)

I have revoked all my certificates and regenerated new ones, I switched the code signing for both app and Widget to manually specify the profile and identity making sure that both targets are built on the same certificate. I removed my Apple ID from XCode, deleted derived data, restarted XCode, restarted the MAC, deleted the certificates from key chain and re-downloaded them, changed the certificate to be always trusted and back to System defaults, I deleted all provisioning profiles and re-downloaded them (several times).

I am not sure what else to do as I've been having this issue for over a week now and I cannot build my application for ad-hoc testing.

Comment: Have you checked all the differences in both embedded and parent app project build settings concerning certificates? Some older data stuck in configuration could vex

Comment: Yes both the app and the widget share the same certificate. At least that what I can find. What settings do you have in mind that I need to check beside the code signing settings?

Comment: I meant all combinations of codesigning parameters in various build settings vs. project vs. target combinations. There are lot of them in project, as you use standalone libraries / widgets

Comment: there all the same